# Bizarre inconsistent python ImportError - possible circular dependency?

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to refactor some python code and I'm stuck with an import error I don't understand.  I suspect there might be a circular dependency somewhere but I don't see it, and I'm not getting much in the way of hints from the error messages.  The codebase is large, but there are two modules of interest here:

`radian/models.py` defines a class called `ACount`

`datalayer/radian.py` has the following line in it:

```
from radian.models import ACount
```

When I run the code (either interactively or from the main program) the imports fail in a way that doesn't make sense to me.

```
>>> from radian.models import ACount
>>> import datalayer.radian
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/leopd/dev/dbproj/datalayer/radian.py", line 10, in <module>
    from radian.models import ACount
ImportError: No module named models
```

My best guess is that there's a circular dependency somewhere -- that `radian` is importing something that imports `datalayer`.  But I don't see it.  And the error message doesn't make any sense to me.  Any ideas what's going on?

-- UPDATE --

I'm using python 2.6.1 on Mac.  The `__init__.py` files have some code in them, but they only import from standard python packages.

Comment: What Python version are you using?  I'd recommend enabling absolute imports if available.

Comment: Does `radian` have an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Could the `radian.py` file be trying to import `models` from itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any module in the `datalayer` folder (including `radian.py`), when it sees `from radian`, will assume that `datalayer/radian.py` is the relevant module. You might need to do

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

in `datalayer/radian.py` and other similarly affected modules, and then check all your imports to ensure that they're absolute. You may be able to get away with renaming `datalayer/radian.py` and the imports which reference it, depending on where that module is referenced from.